# How to group by an Attribute and calculate time between consecutive tickets for that Attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, I am working with a Dataframe where there are around 20 columns, but only two columns are really of importance.

| Index | ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-40-50 | 2021-12-01 16:54:00 |
| 2 | 01-10 | 2021-10-11 13:28:00 |
| 3 | 03-48-58 | 2021-11-05 16:54:00 |
| 4 | 01-40-50 | 2021-12-06 19:34:00 |
| 5 | 03-48-58 | 2021-12-09 12:14:00 |
| 6 | 01-10 | 2021-08-06 19:34:00 |
| 7 | 03-48-58 | 2021-10-01 11:44:00 |

There are 90 different ID's and a few thousand rows in total. What I want to do is:

1. Group the entries by the ID's
2. Order those ID rows by the Date
3. Then calculate the difference between one timestamp to another
4. And create a column that has those entries (to then visualize it for the 90 different ID's)

While I thought it would be an easy thing to use the function groupby, I am having quite a bit of trouble. Would appreciate any input as to how to start this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> df.groupby("ID")["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff())
ID         Index 
01-10      6                     NaT
           2        65 days 17:54:00
01-40-50   1                     NaT
           4         5 days 02:40:00
03-48-58   7                     NaT
           3        35 days 05:10:00
           5        33 days 19:20:00
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for that! If I now have the 90 unique 'ID' the many values in 'Date' for each ID and a new column 'time_difference' that has your value above in it -> How do I best plot 90 different plots?

One plot per ID and the two axis would be time_difference and the Date.

Comment: @Yeladdou nice! I think you'd have to post another question to answer that :P

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for the advice. I'll do that!